# Golang template.ParseFiles "not a directory" error

Tags: templates, go, revel

I'm trying to render just one template:

```
root_path, err := osext.Executable()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
template_path := root_path + "/app/views/mailtemplates/" + "feedback.html"

fmt.Println(exist(template_path))

tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(template_path)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

but I have the error `not a directory`.
My `exist` function:

```
func exist(file_path string) bool {
    if _, err := os.Stat(file_path); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

it returns `true`. What's the problem with `template.ParseFiles`? I see documentation and where written that arguments are `filenames` and `There must be at least one file`. What I doing wrong?

**EDITED:**
My variables:

```
root_path: /home/cnaize/Dropbox/develop/gocode/bin/advorts
template_path: /home/cnaize/Dropbox/develop/gocode/bin/advorts/app/views/mailtemplates/feedback.html
```

My file's content:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello, World!
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDITED 2:** I've moved all my projects, libs and etc to `/home/cnaize/gocode` and now I have error:

```
open /home/cnaize/gocode/bin/advorts/app/views/mailtemplates/feedback.txt: not a directory
```

Is it `Revel`'s problem? What I supposed to do? I've tried to remove this bin file, didn't helped.

Comment: Can you post the output of `osext.Executable()` and also `template_path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue was a path within the `Dropbox/` folder: consider it is synchronized/managed by an external process (`dropbox`), the ability to access the file isn't always reliable.

Putting the file outside of that Dropbox path would solve the issue.

Comment: I've updated my post. I don't know what is incorrect in this template

Comment: @cnaize if your path is managed by dropbox, could you try with a file in a simpler path, outside of Dropbox, just for testing? like `/home/cnaize/feedback.html`

Comment: thx! how it works! I don't know what's wrong with `Dropbox` folder

Comment: @cnaize Ok, I have edited the answer to reflect the actual issue.

Comment: I've updated my post, now problem with my bin file, can you help me?